# How to remove "Your Odoo is not supported. Upgrade now or register your contract here"

Tags: openerp, odoo

How to remove "Your Odoo is not supported.  Upgrade now or register your contract here"?
That is, without actually registering a contract with OpenERP SA.

[image: Not supported]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [oerp_no_phoning_home](https://bitbucket.org/BizzAppDev/oerp_no_phoning_home) and place it in one of your addons directories

```
`git clone https://bitbucket.org/BizzAppDev/oerp_no_phoning_home.git`
```

You can set it up like this:

- In Settings click "Update Modules List".
- Unselect the "Installed" text in the search box, replace with e.g. 'home'.
- Install the "Stop Phoning Home" module.

For OpenERP v7 there's also this addon: https://www.odoo.com/apps/7.0/web_adblock/

As of Odoo 8.08 you may have to try this: http://odoo.guide/debranding-odoo-backend/

Comment: It doesn't completely work for do 8.08 latest... any plans on updating it?

Comment: See this guide: http://odoo.guide/debranding-odoo-backend/

Answer (score -1):

If you use Adblock Plus, it's as simple ad adding a rule for:

```
##td.announcement_bar
```

and you're done.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how to do that?  Thanks.

Comment: @jrial did you read the tags??

Comment: @FranciscoTapia: you mean "Odoo" and "OpenERP"? I worked there for 3.5 years, and that was what we used internally. Perhaps it no longer works now since they changed the layout. At the time of writing though, this is how we blocked it.